# How to process all map outputs in one reducer at the same time?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have written a MapReduce application in which the mappers produce output in the following form:

```
 key1    value1
 key2    value2
 keyn    valuen
```

What I want to do is to sum all of the values for all the keys in my reducer. Basically:

```
sum = value1+value2+value3
```

Is that possible? From what I understand currently the reducer is called separately for each key/value pair. One solution that came to my mind was to have a private sum variable maintaining the sum of the values process thus far in it. In that case, however, how do I know that all of the pairs have been processed so that the sum may be written out to the collector?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the key then use a single, constant key.  If you have to have several key values, you could set the number of reducers to 1 and use an instance variable in the reducer class to hold the sum of all the values.  Initialize the variable in the setup() method and report the overall sum in the close() method.

Another approach would be to write the sum of the values for a given key by incrementing a counter with the sum in the reduce method.  Let hadoop bring all the values together in a single counter value.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to Hadoop and while doing research on the same problem, I     found out the Mapper and Reducer classes also have setup() and cleanup() methods     along with  map() and reduce().

**First, set number of Reducers to 1.**

```
public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
int sum=0
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      for (IntWritable value : values) 
        {
            sum += value.get();
        }
}

@Override
protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  context.write(new Text("Sum:", new IntWritable(sum));
  }
}
```